# Why are usb hubs only available up to 7 ports?

Tags: usb

Why are usb hubs only available up to 7 ports? Is there something technical that prevents that? I thought USB addressing allowed 127 USB devices to be connected, so that's not it.

EDIT: Thanks for the links for hubs with more ports. There are a lot of them with 7 ports, and I'd never seen one with more. I didn't think 7 was the technical limit, I just wondered why 7 seemed to be so universal.

Here's what I have that plugs into USB:

1. mouse
2. keyboard
3. ipod
4. ipod shuffle
5. camera
6. joystick
7. rudder pedals
8. throttle quadrant
9. gps
10. external HD
11. memory stick
12. cell phone

Answer (score 23):

Why should the theoretical port number be limited to only seven ports? There are hubs with more ports on the market.

Look at this monster example:
[49-port USB hub is just plain practical](http://www.crunchgear.com/2009/05/28/49-port-usb-hub-is-just-plain-practical/)

[image]
<sub>(source: [crunchgear.com](http://www.crunchgear.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/49ph_populated-with-dongles.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Why did this get voted down? I'm new here so I'll admit I don't understand the culture completely but this answer showed us that there are hubs larger than 7 ports and it entertained a bit.

Comment: Not a clue!    I thought it was good and gave it a +1   :)

Comment: Perhaps it was marked down because it's not available yet? I think it's awesome though.

Answer (score 7):

I think the main issue is power.

I'm not going to look up the technical numbers and figures, but if you put too many devices on a hub, The USB port won't be able to supply enough power to all the devices.

[Here is a USB hub with 16 ports](http://www.gizmag.com/brando-super-16-port-usb-hub/9691/) (8 on each side) and it uses an external power source.

edit: the 13 port hub posted earlier also has an external power supply...

Comment: This one doesn't seem to be available yet either.

Answer (score 6):

The 7 comes from the spec.  The theoretical limit for USB is 127 devices which is (2^7)-1.  It would be 128 because there are 7 bits for the address, but address 0 is reserved. So we have 127.  Did you notice how the 49 port hub is a multiple of 7?  Also, there is an upper limit of 7 tiers of devices which is explained in these articles:

http://www.totalphase.com/support/kb/10047/

http://www.usblyzer.com/usb-topology.htm

Answer (score 2):

Here is a 13 port usb hub.

[13 port USB hub](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817364017)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because no one (as in 99.9999%)  has a use for more then 7 ports ?

Comment: It's getting pretty ridiculous how many USB ports we need.  I have 1)2) 2 USB Thumb Drives.  3) A USB Mouse. 4) A USB Keyboard 5) USB Speakers 6) A USB Headphone/microphone. 7) A USB Webcam. 8) A USB Printer 9) A USB CardReader (CF, SD, etc..). 10) A USB Cable Modem. 11) iPod. 12) Digital Camera.  That's 12 devices, which I need to  mostly all plug in at once, and I don't think i'm all that atypical.

Comment: You should try Ethernet for your cable modem.  It's faster than USB and could be run through a router and shared.

Answer (score 1):

There are hubs with more then 7 ports, I've seen hubs with 10, 13 ports usually. However, a USB host can have only 7 devices attached to it. Therefore, when there are more ports then 7 in a USB hub, there are several logical hubs inside.

So, I think, the 13 port hub internally is organized as two hubs connected one to the other:

a) primary 7 port hub, of which 1 port is used for uplink for the secondary hub, so has 6 free ports

b) secondary second 7 port hub, with 7 ports.

Together, it is 6+7=13 ports.

Therefore, the 13 ports are not equal, 6 are closer to the root hub, and 7 ports are 1 level further away.
This can be important in some cases when many hubs are daisy chained. Recently I got a warning in Windows 8 saying I have too many USB hubs daisy chained, and devices more then 5 level away from the root will have problems, so I had to reconfigure them.

The practical consequence of this is that it's better to have one hub which acts as a "source" for all other hubs, instead of plugging one hubs sequentially, to minimize the distance from the root.

I have tried many USB 2.0 hubs recently, in the end I have settled with an [EXSYS EX-1177](http://www.exsys.ch/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=210&language=en&zenid=8f72c1dfab539b12e72d987c741468a9). It provides sufficient power for external HDD drives, and non-powered USB hubs. I use it as the lowest level hub, and other hubs are attached to this one.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that power is a concern, as suggested, but also that the market for hubs over a certain size isn't big enough to make it worth pushing them as a common item.